# Python3: use exec() to create a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-7, exec

I am using tkinter to create an app and currently I made a lot of buttons so I need to bind all buttons with different command, I will like to use `exec()` to create functions.

```py
strategy=None
exec("global commandbutton"+str(len(strategicpoint)+1)+"\ndef commandbutton"+str(len(strategicpoint)+1)+"():\n\tglobal strategy\n\tstrategy="+str(len(strategicpoint)))
commandline=eval('commandbutton'+str(len(strategicpoint)+1))
imgx=tk.Button(win,image=towert,command=commandline)
```

for cleaner solutions:

```py
global commandbutton{...}
def commandbutton{...}():
    global strategy
    strategy={...}
```

I want my code run like above and it runs, but later I call the command and test to `print(strategy)`, (I have clicked the button/invoked the command) it prints `None` when I want it to print something else.

Comment: That looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: Bad idea. Don't do it.

Comment: I must try that or I will need to copy&paste a lot of functions which makes my project large :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use `exec()` or `eval()` here.

- Functions don't have to be named sequentially. You can store function objects in a loop variable too and use that loop variable to create a tkinter hook.
- You can create functions with a bound parameter without `exec`, using a closure, or just by binding the parameter in a lambda function or `functools.partial()`.

So if you have a loop with an incrementing `strategicpoint` value, I'd just do this:

```
def set_strategy(point):
    global strategy
    strategy = point

buttons = []
for strategicpoint in range(1, number_of_points + 1):
    imgx = tk.Button(win, image=towert, command=lambda point=strategicpoint: set_strategy(point))
    buttons.append(imgx)
```

The `lambda point=...` part binds the current loop value as a default value for the `point` argument of the new function object that `lambda` creates. When that function is called without arguments (as would be done when clicking the button), then the new function uses the integer value that was assigned to `strategicpoint` at the time, to call `set_strategy(point)`.

You can also use a closure, a local variable in an outer function, that an inner function makes use of. Nested, inner functions inside an outer function are created each time you call the outer function, so they are separate from other function objects created by the same outer function:

```
def create_strategy_command(strategypoint):
    def set_strategy():
        global strategy
        strategy = strategypoint
    return set_strategy
```

then when creating your buttons, use:

```
imgx = tk.Button(win, image=towert, command=create_strategy_command(strategicpoint))
```

Note that calling the `create_strategy_command()` function returns a new function here, used as the button command.

Comment: wow thanks dude it works!!! Lambda is amazing! Although I don't use it:) [cuz I sucks in lambda]

Comment: TIL you could return functions from functions. Smart and useful for given scenarios.

Comment: this can be useful when I make my next project(sudoko)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Use a dictionary to store all your functions, as such:

```py
option = "default"
def change_option(target):
    global option
    option = target

def f1():
    print("foo")
def f2():
    print("bar")

my_functions = {
    "select1": f1,
    "select2": f2
    "default": None
    }

imgx=tk.Button(win,image=towert,command=my_functions[option])  # None
swapper = tk.Button(win, image=towert, lambda: change_option("select2")) # button to change the command if you want it
imgx=tk.Button(win,image=towert,command=my_functions[option]) # print("bar")
change_option("select1")
imgx=tk.Button(win,image=towert,command=my_functions[option]) # print("foo")
```

You could probably get by without using a dictionary, but in my opinion this is rather clean. Don't ever use exec() or eval(), unless you absolutely know what security concerns it has, you know the product wont be used on another machine, or you really don't have another choice.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but I mean I need to create **a lot of functions**, and the answer above works, if I can vote, I will probably upvote you but I can't :)

Comment: as I said, I made a lot of buttons in tkinter :)